# Junit report showing only java output in console and not junitreport

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, junit

I am completely new to junit. Trying to create junit reports. I have linked two projects, main file is in one project which is running test cases from other project.

This is my build.xml file

as the first entry and export the buildfile again. -->

and this is my output

```
Buildfile: E:\Workspace\cd5 Main Project 16-09-2014\build.xml
build-subprojects:
init:
build-project:
 [echo] cd5 Main Project 16-09-2014: E:\Workspace\cd5 Main Project 16-09-2014\build.xml
[javac] E:\Workspace\cd5 Main Project 16-09-2014\build.xml:134: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] E:\Workspace\cd5 Main Project 16-09-2014\build.xml:138: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] E:\Workspace\cd5 Main Project 16-09-2014\build.xml:142: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] E:\Workspace\cd5 Main Project 16-09-2014\build.xml:146: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] E:\Workspace\cd5 Main Project 16-09-2014\build.xml:150: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] E:\Workspace\cd5 Main Project 16-09-2014\build.xml:154: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
build:
Application:
 [java] 12:13:58.627 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG neo4j.xafactory - Opened [E:\Workspace\cd5 Main Project 16-09-2014\workspace\untitled71\nioneo_logical.log.1] clean empty log, version=1, lastTxId=95
 [java] .Testcase id: PluginModelTest.testCreateParameter.PMTCP1
 [java] PluginModelTest.testCreateParameter(): model: jp.sbi.celldesigner.plugin.api.impl.PluginModelImpl@cedaea
 [java] expectedParamId: a5
 [java] Parameter successfully created: Testcase successful: 
 [java] PluginModelImpl.deleteParameter(): id to delete: a5
 [java] .Testcase id: PluginModelTest.testCreateParameter.PMTCP2
 [java] PluginModelTest.testCreateParameter(): model: jp.sbi.celldesigner.plugin.api.impl.PluginModelImpl@cedaea
 [java] expectedParamId: a6
 [java] Parameter successfully created: Testcase successful: 
 [java] PluginModelImpl.deleteParameter(): id to delete: a6
 [java] Time: 0.745
 [java] OK (2 tests)
```

The tests are running fine but TESTS-TestSuites.xml is not getting generated.What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get more information about Junit report in the below given reference link:

[JunitReport link](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html)

Comment: I went through that, I am still stuck since my xml file is not getting generated.

Comment: can you just add these tags at start and end of your build file and check..
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="demo" default="test"> your content here...</project>`

Comment: Its there, I failed to paste it.

Comment: can you please edit your question so that any other person who wants to answer your question can understand better.

Comment: Is it possible to fuse 2 build files and generate a report? Since my main file is in one project which is calling test files from another project.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

Even if you `Application` target is calling your `PluginModelTest` from another project, I still don't see how your `junitreport` target is linked to your `PluginModelTest` target.

Try add an [`antcall`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) task to the end of your `PluginModelTest`:

```
<antcall target="junitreport">
```

**Original Answer**

Both the `CDModelImplTest` and `junitreport` targets look right to me. But the test case shows in your build output (`PluginModelTest`) is different from that in your build script (`CDModelImplTest`)...

UPDATE: The first thing to try is to update your `junitreport` target so that it depends on the `CDModelImplTest`. This will ensure that the tests are executed before the report generation tasks are executed.

```
<target name="junitreport" depends="CDModelImplTest">
```

Also, I don't see your `${junit.output.dir}` being set anywhere in the build file. Unless you are passing its value in from the command line, try add this property assignment to the top of your build file:

```
<property name="junit.output.dir" value="test-results"/>
```

All your unit test results and reports will then be saved into a `test-results` folder.

Alternately, you can pass this property into your build script from command line via something like (which will only work after you added the `depends` attribute as above):

```
ant -Djunit.output.dir=test-results junitreport
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The target Application is in one project which is calling PluginModelTest from other project. Maybe that is why its showing in the result.I made all the required changes. But still xml files are not generating.

Comment: Is it possible to fuse 2 build files and generate a report? Since my main file is in one project which is calling test files from another project.

Comment: You can call one from within the other using the [antcall](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) task. See my updated answer.